# Customized Generated HTML + GridView Capabilities

Tags: html, css, asp.net, gridview

ASP.NET's GridView controller is great, it's easy to use, it offers sorting, paging, and other stuff, but I find it difficult to customize the way it looks.

The GridView will always generated a table with headers and divided columns, but sometimes I need the users to see a better looking listed items, customized using CSS.

---

**In other words, I don't want something like this:**

[image]

---

**I want something like this:**

[image]

---

But when I'm going to generate the HTML and customize the way it looks, it would take time to implement the paging and sorting by myself, from scratch.

So How can I mix the Customized HTML with the Capabilities of GridView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the `Repeater`!  Complete control over layout and rendering, but the downside is a lot of the built-in stuff like paging and sorting is not there.

I've actually used a `Repeater` combined with ASPNET Pager: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11418/Pager-Control-for-ASP-NET, and I also rolled my own multi-sort.

It's more work than a `GridView`, but if you want complete control, there's no better option.